# UIViewController modalPresentationStyle popover for iPad and custom for iPhone

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipresentationcontroller, uitraitcollection, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I created a custom presentation using `UIPresentationController` but I only want to use this presentation for horizontally compact layout, and I want to replace my custom presentation with a popover for horizontally regular layout, and when the horizontal trait collection updates between compact and regular I want my presentation style to update between the two.

In `UIPresentationController` class there is `adaptivePresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationStyle` which as I understand it is used as the presentation style for horizontal compact layouts. I can return `custom` but I'm not sure how to use my other `UIPresentationController` and set up `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`

Comment: Hi Max, I'm currently trying to accomplish the same thing. Did you ever found a solution?